# I live with my family but I dnt like hot weather, is it ok to seal a vent?

Tags: heating

[image]

I live with my family but I do not like hot weather. Thus is it ok to seal the vent in the below part?

Comment: No images showed up. Are you referring to a register in your bedroom?

Comment: Not enough information. Please add detailed description of your vent and what is for.

Comment: What does living with your family have to do with it?